# probability distribution Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image]

Given this transition matrix of a Markov chain the question is:
What is the probability distribution for the length of a continuous period of being in state A? What is the average length of this period?

I have calculated the stationary probabilities but otherwise I am not really sure what this question is asking. Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The stationary probabilities are unnecessary work here.

The transition matrix tells us that from state $A$, we go to state $H$ with probability $0.5$, and stay in state $A$ with probability $0.5$. So:

- If we stay in $A$ for $1$ step, then as soon as we get to $A$, we immediately transition $A \to H$. What is the probability that this happens?
- If we stay in $A$ for $2$ steps, then once we get to $A$, the next two steps must be $A \to A \to H$. What is the probability that this happens?
- In general, if we stay in $A$ for $k$ steps, that means that after getting to $A$, the next $k$ steps must be $A \to A \to \dots \to A \to H$ (with $k-1$ transitions $A \to A$). What is the probability that this happens?

These probabilities tell us the probability distribution; from there, you can compute its expected value in the usual way.